# trouble with calculating neighbors in the graph

Tags: r, loops, igraph, nearest-neighbor

I have a graph:

```
>  graf
IGRAPH 12ffd7b UNW- 16 16 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), color (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from 12ffd7b (vertex names):
 [1] 0--1  0--2  0--15 2--3  2--4  2--5  2--7  2--8  2--10 2--11 2--12 2--14 4--6  4--9  8--13 1--5
```

licznik are 4 vectors that are looking for neighbors

> ```
> licznik
> [1] "8" "3" "1" "7"
> ```

```
for (v in licznik)
        {
          y<- neighbors(graf,v)
          print(y)
        zarazeni1 <- c(zarazeni1, y)  
        }
        wspolne = c(zarazeni1)
```

the result "wspolne ", it gives 2 result, the top row is good results (agrees with the graph), unfortunately he also receives the second result, which is incorrect

```
> wspolne
   2   13    2    0    5    2 
 "2" "16"  "2"  "1"  "8"  "2"
```

where I commit, error

edit

```
    dput(graf)
structure(list(16, FALSE, c(4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 7), c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 4), c(1, 4, 7, 0, 2, 3, 5, 15, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14), c(1, 0, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), 
    c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
    ), c(0, 3, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
    16, 16, 16), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        structure(list(name = c("0", "2", "4", "8", "1", "15", 
        "3", "5", "7", "10", "11", "12", "14", "6", "9", "13"
        ), color = c("green", "green", "green", "blue", "blue", 
        "green", "blue", "green", "blue", "green", "green", "green", 
        "green", "green", "green", "green")), .Names = c("name", 
        "color")), structure(list(weight = c(0.0478016305714846, 
        0.731876280624419, 0.282143459422514, 0.998805105453357, 
        0.814432282699272, 0.957247303100303, 0.734987537842244, 
        0.41236763051711, 0.645621495554224, 0.488656249130145, 
        0.0478016305714846, 0.731876280624419, 0.282143459422514, 
        0.998805105453357, 0.814432282699272, 0.957247303100303
        )), .Names = "weight")), class = "igraph")
```

Comment: please share example data using `dput()`

Comment: `dput(wspolne)
structure(c("2", "16", "2", "1", "8", "2"), .Names = c("2", "13", 
"2", "0", "5", "2"))`

Comment: of your input data `graf`, and please edit that into the post.

Comment: @Kubazooo  Your `dput(graf)` has unbalanced parentheses.  Please check.